# images not loading in wampserver

Tags: apache, codeigniter, xampp, localhost, wampserver

I have installed  wamp server in windows 8 and I have enabled mod_rewrite and also changed AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All. Icons are not being loaded in the localhost. I am not able to figure out the error. Please help me to solve this issue.

[image: Image showing icons are not being loaded in localhost]

Answer (score 0):

Please inspect the source(using F12) and try to check the images path whether they are valid or not. If they have local path then check existence of images at respective location or if the path is external then check your internet connection.